# How to say "please be strict with me" in Japanese

Tags: word-choice, meaning, questions, spoken-language, politeness

I'm trying to figure out how to say

> "please be strict with me"

For when I am practising with conversation exchanges.

So far I have come up with:

1. 私と厳しくしてください
2. 私に厳しくてさられてお願いします

Are any of these close to accurate?
Any help that could be offered would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 私*に*厳しくしてください (but do you really want someone to be strict with you?)

Comment: Well, in terms of if I make a mistake I would like them to feel they can correct me on it. Thank you :)